# trying to add a series of text to a string for (fivem)

Tags: fivem

im editing a script i received, after adding code to the top of script and fixing any issues with what i added it now says ~593: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 455) near 'function'
Not sure what im doing wrong as im fairly new to LUA coding and help would be appreciated!

```
--en
Text = {

    ['hood_closed'] = 'hood closed!',
    ['mechanic_action_complete'] = 'repair finished',
    ['mechanic_action_started'] = 'repair started',
    ['wrong_job'] = 'wrong Job',
    ['not_enough'] = 'not enough items',
    
    --Added
    ['vehicle_locked'] = 'vehicle locked!',
    ['vehicle_nearby'] = 'no vehicle nearby!',
    ['vehicle_notonlift'] = 'vehicle not on the lift!',
    ['vehicle_notoncarjack'] = 'vehicle not on the carjack!',
    
  --Parts Stuff
    ['install_engine'] = '[~r~E~w~] install engine',
    ['repair_engine'] = '[~r~E~w~] repair engine',
    ['installing_engine'] = '~r~engine is being installed',
    ['repairing_engine'] = '~r~engine is being repaired',
    ['install_turbo'] = '[~r~E~w~] install turbo',
    ['repair_turbo'] = '[~r~E~w~] repair turbo',
    ['installing_turbo'] = '~r~turbo is being installed',
    ['repairing_turbo'] = '~r~turbo is being repaired',
    ['install_nitro'] = '[~r~E~w~] install nitro',
    ['repair_nitro'] = '[~r~E~w~] repair nitro',
    ['installing_nitro'] = '~r~nitro is being installed',
    ['repairing_nitro'] = '~r~nitro is being repaired',
    ['exchange_oil'] = '[~r~E~w~] change oil',
    ['refill_oil'] = '[~r~E~w~] refill oil',
    ['refilling_oil'] = '~r~oil is being refilled',
    ['exchanging_oil'] = '~r~oil is being changed',
    ['install_transmission'] = '[~r~E~w~] install transmission',
    ['repair_transmission'] = '[~r~E~w~] repair transmission',
    ['installing_transmission'] = '~r~transmission is being installed',
    ['repairing_transmission'] = '~r~transmission is being repaired',
    ['install_tire'] = '[~r~E~w~] install tire',
    ['install_brakes'] = '[~r~E~w~] install brake',
    ['install_suspension'] = '[~r~E~w~] install suspension',
    
        
    --New
    ['install_sparkplugs'] = '[~r~E~w~] install sparkplugs'
}



  function SendTextMessage(msg)

        SetNotificationTextEntry('STRING')
        AddTextComponentString(msg)
        DrawNotification(0,1)

        --EXAMPLE USED IN VIDEO
        --exports['mythic_notify']:SendAlert('inform', msg)
 end
```

593: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 455) near 'function'

im just lost at this point